# Better way for access to Amazon S3 Infrequent Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am going to use [Amazon S3 Infrequent Access](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/). I have played around and found that it is possible to access this service in two ways.

1. [Making Requests Using the REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAPI.html). This way looks pretty simple and clear.
2. Using [Amazon API gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/). I am not big expert in this service and one different that I have found that [payload size is limited to 10 MB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html).

What other advantages/disadvantages has using Amazon S3 Infrequent Access via Amazon API gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use Amazon S3, then you should call S3 directly. This can be done via the REST API or via [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk) for most popular programming languages.

You can also use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which makes it possible to write scripts that can call the AWS API.

[Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/apigateway/) allows you to create your own APIs that can call an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/) function or your own application. It should **not** be used to call Amazon S3 unless you are trying to [Create an API as an Amazon S3 Proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html), which is a rare situation.